# Hiding plain text in email readers: is <--! better than <div dislay:none or is there a better way?

Tags: email, html-email

I am trying to include, in email, a simple text alternative for non html email readers.

I can not use MIME (service I am using doesn't support it, only HTML only or Text only).

I figure *most* people (95%) have simple html support, so I'll avoid css.
But for the text-only folks I want to include a text-only version.

I have tried hiding it with

- `<div class="TEXT ONLY" style="width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none">`
- `<--!   text here  -->`

And wrapping the second around the first.
That works in Gmail and in Yahoo, outlook ,etc ](per testing here)(http://info.contactology.com/email-view)  and testing in my own gmail account and an ancient 10 year old Goldmine client).

But I'm looking for problems with the above or a **better solution**.  Maybe just using the second option '<--!'  (since, if it *is* displayed it's fewer confusing HTML tags for the user to ignore)

Answer (score 3):

Both of them will make the text invisible,

But,

`<div class="TEXT ONLY" style="width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none">`
will be accessible via the DOM.

where as,
`<--!   text here  -->`
will not be accessible via the DOM.

So ultimately the choice is yours, depending on your requirements. If just hiding the element is your only concern then I would rather prefer the `<--!   text here  -->`. This can hide anything including entire html contents too (unless it includes `-->`), where as, the DIV way may cause problems with the DOM in certain cases.

Comment: Since it's an email and most email clients strip out any JavaScript for security purposes, being able to access the DOM isn't a priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following technique that I employ to emulate "email preview text". Quick background (in case you're interested): Most email clients grab alt text and link text to generate preview text, but my company includes multiple images and a "click to view in browser" link before any informative content, so the generated preview text is garbage.

I add the following code right after the opening `body` tag:

```
<!--email preview text-->
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0;max-width:0;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">
    Here is my preview text. You should have roughly 90 characters and include a call-to-action. Read on to find out more.
</div><!--/email preview text-->
```

Adapted from [Litmus.com](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support).